# Microsoft Excel VBA sum function not working

Tags: vba, excel

When i run the code i want the answer of the sum to be displayed in the cell (F 27).

But the sum function does not work nothing is printed into the cells when i run the code. I don't get any errors what so ever.

This is my code

```
Private Sub TextTotal1_Functions()

Dim SumTotal As Long

SumTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F9:F26"))

Range("F27") = SumTotal
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code works for me without issue.  Try your code in a new workbook and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're not specifying the sheet correctly, try the below

```
Private Sub TextTotal1_Functions()

Dim SumTotal As Long

SumTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("MySheetNameHere").Range("F9:F26"))

Sheets("MySheetNameHere").Range("F27") = SumTotal
```

Comment: if you are fully qualifying ranges, you might want to qualify the final range (last line) as well. `Sheets("MySheetNameHere").Range("F27") = SumTotal`

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I use WorksheetFunction in VBA, is to write something like this in the immediate window:

```
?WorksheetFunction.Sum(selection)
```

and to see whether I am getting what I am expecting from the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the Calculation is set to Manual, so set it back to Automatic:

```
Application.calcualtion = xlCalculationAutomatic
```